# Which controller board is best for hooking up rasberry pi to Traxxas 5675 Titan 77?

Tags: motor, dc, raspberry-pi

Can I hook this motor up to my rasberry pi?: [http://www.amazon.com/Traxxas-7075-Titan-Brushless-Motor/dp/B0027GGZYU/ref=pd_sbs_t_4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0027GGZYU)

How about this one? 
[http://www.amazon.com/Traxxas-Titan-Motor-10-Turn-Volts/dp/B001SETT0Y/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1383160714&sr=8-2&keywords=traxxas+titan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001SETT0Y)

What would be the best controller board to use?

What stops this from being hooked up directly to the pi? Is it only voltage? I suspect a controller is needed for precision speed control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not without a controller
2. Not without a controller
3. Best is subjective
4. Many things
5. No

Yes, a controller is needed not only for precision speed control, but also current sourcing. Much to my surprise, these were NOT BLDC motors, they are brushed DC.

You need an ESC -- traxxas sells these as well. Ask them which is most appropriate for your motor.
[This might work.](http://traxxas.com/products/parts/escs/xl25lvd)